# Fall Detection using RNN Machine Learning using accelerometer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have read some documentation and they recommended about using RNN for building model detect the fall. I have accelerometer data from beacon. But i have trouble from the begin. I have a list of accelerometer in 3 axis like this :

```
50-49-27
53-56-35 
57-55-38 
=======
65-49-38 
72-48-57 
68-56-41
```

The "===" is separate different time we fall. How can we preprocessing this data and how can i using RNN model to train these data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: tutorials are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are these raw values that include the gravity vector?  During a fall the magnitude will be less than one because the device is moving in the direction of gravity. You can use the magnitude as a feature for classification.